# Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer Test In Progress

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, test-explorer

In Visual Studio 2010 the Test Results view was able to display the unit test currently in progress.  While using Visual Studio 2012 I have not been able to identify the unit test that is being executed in the Test Explorer.  How would I identify the unit test in progress in Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer?

Comment: Do you mean Test Explorer? Test -> Windows -> Test Explorer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx#BKMK_Running_tests_in_Test_Explorer

Comment: It seems as though the test results view should show exactly that, although I also can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface for `ITestExecutor`, which is a required interface for a unit test plugin shows that RunTests has a context of `IFrameworkHandle`

```
public interface ITestExecutor
{
   void RunTests(IEnumerable<string> sources, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle);
   void RunTests(IEnumerable<TestCase> tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle);
   void Cancel();
}
```

`IFrameworkHandle`has methods for recording the status of the tests

```
RecordStart(TestCase testCase)
RecordResult(TestResult testResult)
RecordEnd(TestCase testCase, TestOutcome testOutcome)
```

So it would appear it is possible for the test window to show an icon while the test is running. However, I built a test fixture using a wizard created class library for MS-Test as I expect it would be the most feature complete of all the runners. I added the following test class

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

There was no indication that the test was running for 10 seconds. So I would say that the VS2012's [Update 3 RC] test window does not show the currently running test. A future update may improve the situation as it seems entirely possible given the unit test framework's API.

Comment: Thank you.  I will see about making a feature request.